# Can't visibly instantiate at runtime via QQmlComponent

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am kidding around with a quite simple QML sample that should end up being some kind of chessboard, but for some reason I can't properly add cells at runtime. A cell is defined using a C++ Class (`BasicCell` which extends `QQuickItem`) and can be styled using Qml (`cell.qml`):

```
BasicCell {
    width: 32
    height: 32
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill : parent
        color : "green"
    }
}
```

I use QQmlComponent to construct instances of this "styled" BasicCell at runtime:

```
QQmlComponent cellComponent(qmlEngine(), cellUrl, this);


// Make sure we could actually load that QML component
if (cellComponent.status() != QQmlComponent::Ready)
{
  std::cerr << "Error loading cell.qml:" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& err : cellComponent.errors())
  {
    std::cerr << "  " << err.toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
  }
}

for (int x = 0; x < mNumTiles.width(); ++x)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < mNumTiles.height(); y++)
  {
    BasicCell* cell = qobject_cast<BasicCell*>(cellComponent.create());
    cell->setParent(this);
    cell->setSize(QSize(tileSize(), tileSize()));
    cell->setGridPos(QPoint(x, y));

    childItems().append(cell);
    mCells.insert(cell->gridPos(), cell);
  }
}
```

When using the QML Debugger I can see that I have ended up with the "correct" hierarchy:

```
Game
  BasicCell
     Rectangle
  BasicCell
     Rectangle
  ...
```

But I can't see a thing ... I double and triple checked: All of those rectangles and basic cells do have the appropriate sizes set.

Getting more and more frustrated, I finally copied the code from the `cell.qml` and pasted it as a direct child into the Board.qml. To my astonishment, this renders the cell exactly as I would have expected it.

What am I missing in my use of `QQmlComponent` that differs from this kind of instantionation in QML?

```
Game
{
    // Should be created at runtime using QQmlComponent
    BasicCell {
        width: 32
        height: 32
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color : "green"
        }
        gridPos: "0,0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell->setParent(this);
```

should be

```
cell->setParentItem(this);
```

> The concept of the visual parent differs from that of the QObject
>   parent. An item's visual parent may not necessarily be the same as its
>   object parent. See Concepts - Visual Parent in Qt Quick for more
>   details.

That was taken from:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickitem.html#parent-prop